# Algorithm to differentiate n pictures

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose you are give N bit arrays of length k. meaning each vector v<sub>i</sub> is of form {1,0,0,1...1} (k components) etc.

now I want to find the minimal index set S = {I<sub>0</sub>, I<sub>1</sub>..., I<sub>q-1</sub>}, with 0 <= I<sub>i</sub> <= k-1 such that

when v<sub>i</sub> evaluated on S, which gives a binary sequence {v<sub>i</sub>[I<sub>0</sub>], v<sub>i</sub>[I<sub>1</sub>] ..} is unique for each v<sub>i</sub>.

So for example if there are 64 vectors {v<sub>0</sub>...v<sub>63</sub>}, the minimal index set |S| could have size 6 given v<sub>i</sub> are pretty long and sufficiently different. Because 2<sup>6</sup> = 64.

The application is that given a fixed list of black-white pictures, 0...63, and you know the input would be one of those pictures, with picture sufficiently large, you only need to check 6 pixel of the input to figure out which picture it is.

This problem seems should already be proved NP or solved somewhere.

Any hint? thanks.

Comment: I don't think you mean k *dimensional* bit arrays, but bit arrays of *length* k (which fits your examples).  *Very* different kind of problem, that.

Comment: `you only need to check 6 pixel of the input to figure out which picture it is` - yes, but _which_ six pixels? - you would have to know that in advance, and there's the rub, I think.

Comment: @ScottHunter Since a list of k 1's and 0's is just a vector in k-dimensional space, I'm not sure they're really different problems.

Comment: In mathy terms, what you're trying to to is find a simple projection of a bunch of vectors that preserves uniqueness. I'm not sure about complexity issues, but I know that issue has been getting a lot of attention from people trying to do data visualization for large data-sets. You might try looking up the projection pursuit method and seeing where that takes you.

Comment: @genisage: A k-dimensional bit array has a binary value for each set values for the k indices, and places no restrictions on the space for each of those indices, which can (potentially) be a *much* larger space.

Comment: @ScottHunter: You're both right -- it's an unfortunate terminology clash.  In programming, "dimension" means what you're saying, but in mathematics, it means the same thing as what programmers mean when they say "length".

Comment: Just as a small observation: set `S` may have size as bad as `k`, when all pictures are fully black, except for one pixel; a different one in each picture.

Comment: We can use a radix tree, which has at most N-1 nodes. hence |S| <= N-1. So by running all (N-1) subset of k indices we would find the best. The latter is O(k^(N-1)), which is not good..

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find an NP-hard problem that corresponds to this, though I'm certain it is NP-hard.  I hope someone can dig one up, as I think I have run into this problem in a few different guises.  If not, I might attempt a reduction later if I get time.

Each column partitions the set of images into two parts; we start with a single set containing all images, and our goal is to reach a partition in which every part (set in the partition) consists of a single image, and which uses the fewest possible columns.

One approach would be to make and solve a [Minimum Set Cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) in which the ground set consists of all k(k-1)/2 *pairs* of images, and for each column v_r we make a set consisting of all image pairs that this column *distinguishes* -- i.e. all pairs of images (i, j) such that v_r[i] != v_r[j].  Then any cover will distinguish every image from every other image, and a cover of minimum size will do so using the fewest possible columns.

The fastest way to actually solve this set cover problem is likely to be by formulating and solving an [ILP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), but [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) would also work, and can also be easily turned into a (fast but possibly suboptimal) heuristic.

Either way, here are a few simple reduction rules you can apply before trying to solve the problem (and after each column is added, if you use B&B) that will often reduce the problem size a bit:

1. A column provides the same "distinguishing power" if you change all its 1s to 0s and vice versa.  Therefore "canonicalise" the columns by inverting them if their first element is, say, 1.
2. Collapse all identical columns into a single column, since any of them is exactly as good as any other.  This can easily be done by first sorting them: then all identical columns form a single contiguous block.  Doing this after performing the first reduction will result in more reduction.
3. You can of course delete any "constant columns" -- there is no way they can be of use in distinguishing images.
4. If you have any pair of identical rows, then there is no solution: that is, even including all k bits would not enable you to distinguish these two rows (images).